# How to store expressions in variables and reuse them in a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So let's say that I have a database with the following table:

```
--------------------------
id  | arg1 | arg2 |  arg3
--------------------------
1   |   7  |   3  |   9  |
2   |   5  |   9  |   5  |
```

And let's say I want to do a SUM query that figures some calculations, such as:

```
SELECT SUM( ( arg1 + arg2 + arg3 ) / ( arg1 + arg2 + arg3 ) * ( arg1 + arg2 + arg3 ) )
```

This would be a lot simpler if there was a way to somehow store `( arg1 + arg2 + arg3 )` in a variable (let's say, called `arg_sum`), and then we could do:

```
SELECT SUM( arg_sum / arg_sum * arg_sum )
```

I know this is a pretty contrived example, but I've run into real world scenarios where it would *really* make things more readable if I could store equations in variables and reuse them. Is that possible?

Something maybe like this (except I ideally wouldn't want `added` included in the result set):

```
SELECT SUM( arg1 + arg2 + arg3 ) as arg_sum, SUM( arg_sum / arg_sum * arg_sum ) FROM my_table;
```

Comment: You need to use subqueries.  Or in MySQL 8.0, CTEs.

Comment: I thought subqueries might be the way to go, but I can't figure out in my brain how it would work or be organized. Can you point me in the right direction as far as structure of the query?

Comment: That's a table, not a database. Consider amending your schema. Enumerated columns can be symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: Ehh...it's totally made up. I just used `arg1`, `arg2`, etc. so that the focus wouldn't be on the column names. I fixed the typo of calling the table a database though.

Comment: But still, args 1, 2, and 3 look like they might be the same kind of thing. If they are, then it might be more appropriate to store them in the same column.

Comment: What your MySQL version? If it's 8.x or newer the solution can use CTEs. Otherwise you could use MySQL variables

Comment: @TheImpaler Any chance you could turn that into an answer, with an example of each (using the equation in my question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use compute their values and name them in a **table expression** that you use in the 'FROM' clause. For example:

```
create table abc (
  id int,
  arg1 int,
  arg2 int,
  arg3 int
);

insert into abc (id, arg1, arg2, arg3) values (1, 7, 3, 9); -- sum = 19
insert into abc (id, arg1, arg2, arg3) values (2, 4, 9, 5); -- sum = 18

select *, sum(arg_sum  / arg_sum * arg_sum) as result
  from (
    select *, (arg1 + arg2 + arg3) as arg_sum from abc
  ) x
  where id = 1;
```

Result:

```
id  arg1  arg2  arg3  arg_sum  result
--  ----  ----  ----  -------  ------
1   7     3     9     19       19
```

Comment: This is awesome, and totally answers my question. Thank you! Bonus question: if I have multiple equations that I want to store in table expressions, how would I do that? For example, what if in your example `result` actually needed to be `sum(arg_sum  / arg_sum * arg_sum + arg_division ) as result`, and I had to build both `arg_sum` and `arg_division` for it?

Comment: Just add as many expressions in the inner query (and give them names) as you need. They show up as columns of the `x` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a temporary table like this:

Let's say your main table's name is `args`

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempSums 
SELECT 
      args.id,
      arg1 + arg2 + arg3 as `sum` from args
```

Now, you can use `TempSums` Table like this:

```
SELECT SUM( ( `sum` ) / ( `sum` ) * ( `sum` ) ) FROM TempSums
```

Answer (score 0):

By way of example...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,arg INT NOT NULL
,val INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,arg)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,7),
(1,2,3),
(1,3,9),
(2,1,5),
(2,2,9),
(2,3,5);


SELECT SUM(arg_sum/(arg_sum*arg_sum)) 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id, SUM(val) arg_sum FROM my_table GROUP BY id)n;
+--------------------------------+
| SUM(arg_sum/(arg_sum*arg_sum)) |
+--------------------------------+
|                         0.1053 |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Off-topic. It's clearly a contrived database structure in my question, and I think it's a little silly to talk about how to optimize it. This also has nothing to do with the question. (But in the same vein as your critique, you may have a problem with your id's ;-).

Comment: @Pete My ids are correct according to your example.